# Knowing number of nodes on a graph given depth and span

Tags: graph-theory

How can I know the maximum number of nodes in a graph, given that every node has degree `K` and that the graph has a diameter of at most `N`?

For instance, for a graph of diameter 2 having 3 edges per node, that would give 10 nodes. Is there any general formula for this?

Comment: Si I guess the depth is the diameter ?  i.e. the longest shortest path between 2 nodes ?

Comment: @ManuelLafond yes